# OSError libtorch_global_deps.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning, libtorch

I am trying to replicate the experiments from https://github.com/QData/spacetimeformer.

After creating the environment and running the script provided in the **Example Spacetimeformer Training Commands** section of the repo, I get the following stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "train.py", line 7, in <module>
import pytorch_lightning as pl
File "/home/fsuser/miniconda3/envs/spacetimeformer/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import Callback  # noqa: E402
File "/home/fsuser/miniconda3/envs/spacetimeformer/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/callbacks/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks.base import Callback
File "/home/fsuser/miniconda3/envs/spacetimeformer/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/callbacks/base.py", line 21, in <module>
import torch
File "/home/fsuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 196, in <module>
_load_global_deps()
File "/home/fsuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 149, in _load_global_deps
ctypes.CDLL(lib_path, mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
File "/home/fsuser/miniconda3/envs/spacetimeformer/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 369, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /home/fsuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_global_deps.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The same stack trace is replicable by simply importing `torch` in a .py script.

I've checked /home/fsuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/ and there is no libtorch_global_deps.so file. Do I have to pull it from somewhere or install some other torch library?

I'm running this code on Ubuntu 20.04, python3.8 torch1.9.0 and cuda 10.2.

Comment: I guess you need to install pytorch again inside the `spacetimeformer` environment